# Android SlowGradleBuild

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

Hi there after the update in AndroidStudio+Kotlin does my gradle takes 5min+. The gradle Sync goes fast but the gradle build are just loading forever.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

**apply plugin: 'com.android.application'**

**apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'**

Please check below code and provide any suggestion to help me out.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myApp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/fonts'] } }
    }

    dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.jkcclemens:khttp:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.12.1'
    implementation ('com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.3.0') {
        transitive = false

    }
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.18'
    implementation 'com.github.whalemare:sheetmenu:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.18'

    implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'){
        transitive = false

    }


    }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    }
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be solution if you increased heap size in your project:

For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 4608 MB (based on the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 4g). (This is example size, yours may vary)

To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M in the project gradle.properties.

For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good article you can read, [here](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-decrease-your-gradle-build-time-by-65-310b572b0c43).  But basically, you can update your gradle.properties file like so:

```
#Enable daemon
org.gradle.daemon=true

# Try and findout the best heap size for your project build.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# Modularise your project and enable parallel build
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enable configure on demand.
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

I've done this and it takes me at least 50% less time.